# gc_grace_seconds to remove tombstone rows in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am using awesome Cassandra DB (3.7.0) and I have questions about tombstone.

I have table called `raw_data`. This table has default TTL as 1 hour. This table gets new data every second. Then another processor reads one row and remove the row.

It seems like this `raw_data` table becomes slow at reading and writing after several days of running.

Is this because of deleted rows are staying as tombstone? This table already has TTL as 1 hour. Should I set `gc_grace_period` to something less than 10 days (default value) to remove tombstones quickly? (By the way, I am single-node DB)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting your data is the way to have tombstone problems. TTL is the other way.

It is pretty normal for a Cassandra **cluster** to become slower and slower after each delete, and your cluster will eventually refuse to read data from this table.

Setting `gc_grace_period` to less than the default `10 days` is only one part of the equation. The other part is the compaction strategy you use. Indeed, in order to remove tombstones a compaction is needed.

I'd change my mind about my single-node **cluster** and I'd go with the minimum standard 3 nodes with **RF=3**. Then I'd design my project around something that doesn't explicitly delete data. If you absolutely need to delete data, make sure that C* runs compaction periodically and removes tombstones (or force C* to run compactions), and make sure to have plenty of IOPS, because compaction is very IO intensive.

Comment: Thank you, xmas79. What is C* by the way? I should think about RF=3 eventually. :)

Comment: @diehard98 C* is a shortcut for Cassandra.

Answer (score 4):

In short Tombstones are used to Cassandra to mark the data is deleted, and replicate the same to other nodes so the deleted data doesn't re-appear. These tombstone will be stored in Cassandra till the gc_grace_period. Creating more tobestones might slow down your table. As you are using a single node Cassandra you don't have to replicate anything in other nodes, hence you can update your **gc grace seconds to 1 day**, which will not affect. In future if you are planning to add new nodes and data centers change this gc grace seconds.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like by setting gc_grace_period to very short time, my database runs fine so far. (it has been almost 3 days of continuous running) So, indeed, tombstone was slowing down my query.